# SAM: Custom Lambda Authorizer inside a Lambda Layer

Tags: aws-lambda, authorization, aws-lambda-layers

I had implemented successfully my custom lambda authorizer in a SAM Project.

Now, I'm trying to move this lambda to a lambda layer in order to share this same code among all applications that need it. However, I'm getting some trouble in this effort. It cannot find the referenced file/function:

```
2023-04-24T12:30:17.241Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'authorizerLambda'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'authorizerLambda'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:996:17)",
        "    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1031:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1194:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:1"
    ]
}
```

Here is the partial application's template.yaml:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    CodeUri: lambdas/
    Runtime: nodejs18.x
    Architectures:
      - x86_64
    Layers:
      - !Ref SecurityLayerARN    

  BackendApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Ref Stage
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyLambdaTokenAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          MyLambdaTokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionPayloadType: TOKEN
            IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt MyAuthFunction.Arn

  MyAuthFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: authorizerLambda.authorizerRequestHandle
      Environment:
        Variables:
          JWT_SECRET: !Ref JWTSecret
```

The SecurityLayer ZIP has a "nodejs/authorizerLambda.js" file and exports the `authorizerRequestHandle` function:

```
exports.authorizerRequestHandle = authorizerRequestHandle;
```

What could be wrong? Any tip?

Thanks